# Jquery Autocomplete on hover issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am using jquery auto-complete which is working fine.
the issue is , i am using that in div which is show on hover of text.
when is hover on auto-complete suggestion the div get hide.

[image: Before hover on auto-complete]

[image: After hover on auto-complete]

Comment: Post relevant code please!!

Comment: Yes, please paste your code.

Comment: its simply jquery auto-complete, on Options hover am showing div in that div i place textbox with jquery autocomplete.

Comment: we cant explain without seeing the code you written.

Comment: var $txtListName = $('#<%=txtListName.ClientID %>');
            $txtListName.autocomplete({ source: lname, minLength: 0 });
            $txtListName.focusin(function () { $txtListName.keydown(); });

Comment: @SagarChavan Don't post code in comments. Instead, edit it into the post. The code in the comment above is not causing this behaviour, you've a `focusin` handler, so you probably also have a `focusout` which is a good starting point. I also recommend [reading the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)